# EWS returns ServiceError.ErrorItemNotFound intermittently

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

We have an Outlook plugin that calls back to our server when a new appointment item is saved.  The plugin returns the Outlook item ID.  We call ConvertId to get the EWS item ID.  Here, `itemId` is the Outlook item ID.

```
AlternateId _alternateId = new AlternateId();
_alternateId.Format = idFormat;
_alternateId.Mailbox = mailboxAddress;
_alternateId.UniqueId = itemId;

AlternateIdBase _altBase = _exchangeService.ConvertId(_alternateId, IdFormat.EwsId);
```

This always works, or at least, we always get an EWS item ID returned.

Later, we try to get the appointment item to update it.  Here, `itemId` is the EWS item ID.

```
// get the appointment using the EWS item Id of the appointment
Appointment appointment;
try
{
    appointment = Appointment.Bind(_exchangeService, new ItemId(itemId), propertySet);
    _exchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems(new[] { appointment }, ExchangeWebService.GetRequiredPropertySet());
    return new ExchangeAppointment(appointment, exchangeUserName);
}
```

The problem is that rarely (perhaps 1% of the time) and intermittently, get appointment fails with `ServiceError.ErrorItemNotFound`.  The same user can create a new appointment immediately after the one we have the problem with, and it will work.

We thought that it might be possible for `ConvertId` to return the item ID before the Exchange server had fully synchronised the item from Outlook so we added a retry every 10 seconds for a maximum of 10 minutes.  In all cases where this fails, we see the retries happening but always exceeding 10 minutes at which point we give up and log the exception.

We can see the affected items in Outlook and the users are not deleting them.

The EWS logs simply mirror the `ServiceError.ErrorItemNotFound` exception.

At a loss where to go next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at the values in the failure case. What value is returned from `ConvertId`, and what is the existing value on the item (you can use [EWSEditor](http://ewseditor.codeplex.com) to get this). Maybe by comparing the values you can get a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up on EWSEditor.  I'll give it a go and come back.

Comment: I checked with the editor, thanks, and it shows I've been looking in the wrong direction.  The store ID according to EWS, which I can see is correct because I can search by it and open the item, is different to one returned by the add-in!  I'll raise a separate question for that.  Thanks again.